# Add to serializer data before returning

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an endpoint that looks like this

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def products_view(request):
    some_data = 123
    products = Product.objects.all()
    serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I want to add the `some_data` variable to the JSON this endpoint returns. How could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be the usage of the `to_representation` method of your serializer.
In the following example, the `some_data` will be added in any Product object.

```py
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    ...

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        """ Custom representation """
        to_ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        to_ret['some_data '] = some_data
        return to_ret
```